# Converting 3D into 2D

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have a quad and I'm trying to convert its vertices so that they're facing the camera which is lying at 0,0,1 looking down the Z, or not even specifically facing the camera, just so they're facing up the Z axis. For a test example lets assume the quads vertices are currently:

```
    vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, -1, -1);
    vertices[1] = new Vector3(0, 1, -1);
    vertices[2] = new Vector3(0, 1, 1);
    vertices[3] = new Vector3(0, -1, 1);
```

so they'd be lying along the Z axis, I want to convert that into the X and Y, but I'm not sure how to. I did some googling and read that if you do x/z and y/z then it'll convert it, but the numbers didn't come out correct so I'm guessing there's more to it. In the above example I'd want the vertices converted into:

```
    vertices[0] = new Vector3(-1, -1, 0);
    vertices[1] = new Vector3(-1, 1, 0);
    vertices[2] = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
    vertices[3] = new Vector3(1, -1, 0);
```

Any help would be appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Your question really isn't very clear. What do you mean, for instance, when you say you want vertices to "face up the $z$ axis"? Also, in your example, the vertices that you claim are "lying along the $z$ axis" aren't at all - however, they are in the vertical plane through the $z$ and $y$ axes, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The red point is the camera, at (0,0,2).

The blue connected square is made up of the points: (0, -1, -1) , (0, 1, -1) ,

(0, 1, 1) , (0, -1, 1) .

The green connected square is made up of the points: (-1, -1, 0) , (-1, 1, 0),

(1, 1, 0), (1, -1, 0) .

So I have this picture so far of what you have , if I can't help you with your problem I'll take it down, but what do you want to change?

Comment: I think we need to rotate the points around the y-axis by 90 degrees. $$M=\begin{bmatrix} \cos90&0&\sin90 \\0&1&0\\-\sin90&0&\cos90   \end{bmatrix}$$ , I think we need to rotate the points around the y-axis by 90 degrees.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to re-think about what I was asking. You're right, the points need to be rotated but the blue ones can be any length and can be rotated in any axis. I already know how to rotate around the X, Y and Z, so I guess the question I'm asking is how do I figure out how much I need to rotate the quad around the three axis to get it facing in the direction of the camera.

Comment: So , you're saying the picture isn't static. But if you know the three rotation matrices, the answer is something like R_x(0), R_y(90) ,R_z(0) to get the points to look at the camera. to compute this we multiply R_x * R_y * R_z and use each point in a column to get the result of the rotation. I'll need to try this out.

Comment: Yeah, I think at least the initial question works out, the rotation matrix M above takes the blue points into the green points.

Comment: Yes the picture isn't static, so in that example it is a 90* rotation. But if the blue points are rotated differently how do I figure out the degrees I'm supposed to rotate them in just with the vector points, the camera position and the desired outcome?

Comment: You might study this article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix ( it may be that in a computer graphics context there are better methods of rotation.) I have the following reference: "Computer Graphics" 2nd Edition by Donald Hearn and M. Pauline Baker , Chapter 11 Three-Dimensional Geometric and Modeling Transformation. Foley and Van Dam was another popular reference in it's day, perhaps one of these is available online so you can see the general situation and what you need. Seems like an interesting project!

Comment: Oh, check this out for sure, it is online: http://cs.brown.edu/~avd/ Particularly: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs123/lectures/09_Transformations.pdf